# suddenly read only file system (ext4)

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, kernel

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm getting read only file system(/dev/sda3) randomly. Previously I was using Arch linux(3.14 lts), which had the same problem but discarded due to other problems. I tested the partition with badblocks(read only test) but got no error. Here is the dmesg output after I got the error

```
[   54.223129] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[   54.230217] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
[ 2820.428584] systemd-hostnamed[7046]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 2832.556302] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1f SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 2832.556311] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[ 2832.556318] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2832.556328] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:00:a0:80:76/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 131072 in
[ 2832.556328]          res 41/40:00:68:81:76/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 2832.556334] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2832.556337] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2832.556341] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2832.556350] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:08:a0:81:76/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 131072 in
[ 2832.556350]          res 41/40:08:68:81:76/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[ 2832.556354] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2832.556357] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2832.556361] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2832.556370] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:10:e0:f8:77/00:00:38:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 4096 in
[ 2832.556370]          res 41/40:08:68:81:76/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[ 2832.556374] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2832.556377] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2832.556381] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2832.556388] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:18:20:9c:fe/00:00:37:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 4096 out
[ 2832.556388]          res 41/40:08:68:81:76/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[ 2832.556393] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2832.556396] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2832.556399] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2832.556407] ata1.00: cmd 61/10:20:68:55:f8/00:00:38:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq 8192 out
[ 2832.556407]          res 41/40:08:68:81:76/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[ 2832.556411] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 2832.556414] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 2832.559154] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 2832.559225] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 2832.559231] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559234] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2832.559239] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559244] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 2832.559252] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 2832.559255]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 2832.559276]         00 76 81 68 
[ 2832.559286] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559291] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 2832.559296] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 2832.559300] Read(10): 28 00 00 76 80 a0 00 01 00 00
[ 2832.559317] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 7766376
[ 2832.559325] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919597
[ 2832.559331] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919598
[ 2832.559336] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919599
[ 2832.559347] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919600
[ 2832.559362] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919601
[ 2832.559375] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919602
[ 2832.559387] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919603
[ 2832.559414] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 2832.559419] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559422] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2832.559426] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559429] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 2832.559435] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 2832.559438]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 2832.559459]         00 76 81 68 
[ 2832.559469] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559473] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 2832.559478] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 2832.559481] Read(10): 28 00 00 76 81 a0 00 01 00 00
[ 2832.559499] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 7766432
[ 2832.559504] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919604
[ 2832.559511] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919605
[ 2832.559515] Buffer I/O error on device sda2, logical block 919606
[ 2832.559554] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 2832.559558] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559561] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2832.559584] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559600] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 2832.559635] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 2832.559637]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 2832.559654]         00 76 81 68 
[ 2832.559661] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559664] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 2832.559668] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 2832.559670] Read(10): 28 00 38 77 f8 e0 00 00 08 00
[ 2832.559683] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 947386592
[ 2832.559705] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 2832.559710] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559713] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2832.559717] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559720] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 2832.559725] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 2832.559728]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 2832.559787]         00 76 81 68 
[ 2832.559801] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559804] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 2832.559808] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 2832.559810] Write(10): 2a 00 37 fe 9c 20 00 00 08 00
[ 2832.559823] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 939432992
[ 2832.559829] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error writing to inode 656199 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 117429125)
[ 2832.559835] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 619140
[ 2832.559848] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 2832.559852] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559854] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2832.559858] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559860] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
[ 2832.559864] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[ 2832.559867]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 2832.559907]         00 76 81 68 
[ 2832.559936] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[ 2832.559939] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 2832.559943] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[ 2832.559945] Write(10): 2a 00 38 f8 55 68 00 00 10 00
[ 2832.559958] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 955798888
[ 2832.559973] ata1: EH complete
[ 2832.560359] Aborting journal on device sda3-8.
[ 2832.560568] EXT4-fs error (device sda3): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[ 2832.560579] EXT4-fs (sda3): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 3049.268756] usb 8-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3049.289221] usb 8-1: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387
[ 3049.289229] usb 8-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3049.289235] usb 8-1: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 3049.289239] usb 8-1: Manufacturer: JetFlash
[ 3049.289242] usb 8-1: SerialNumber: C24YX2VM
[ 3049.390235] usb-storage 8-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3049.390386] scsi2 : usb-storage 8-1:1.0
[ 3049.390542] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 3050.389743] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 8GB    8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 3050.390278] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 3050.391841] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 15687680 512-byte logical blocks: (8.03 GB/7.48 GiB)
[ 3050.392121] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3050.392128] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 3050.392293] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 3050.392301] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3050.400811] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 3050.400823] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3050.685511]  sdb: sdb1
[ 3050.686534] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 3050.686540] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3050.686545] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3100.581379] usb 8-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 3121.281998] init: Failed to write to log file /var/log/upstart/modemmanager.log
```

EDIT:

`smartctl --all /dev/sda3` output:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-24-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD050
Serial Number:    62FFS0NSS
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 415d005d5
Firmware Version: AX001C
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Mar 10 22:07:27 2015 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 112) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0027   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       1033
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7111
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   080   080   000    Old_age   Always       -       8335
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   241   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4562
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       3
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
185 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       65535
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       24842
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       613
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   060   036   040    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 40 (0 180 40 26 0)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       130
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12189882
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   086   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       145203
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   060   036   040    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 40 (0 180 40 26 0)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       144
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 25434 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 25434 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8335 hours (347 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 68 81 76 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x00768168 = 7766376

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 20 00 08 b3 40 00      00:39:51.965  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 18 e0 f8 77 40 00      00:39:46.515  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 68 10 58 5d f8 40 00      00:39:46.467  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 a0 81 76 40 00      00:39:44.619  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 80 76 40 00      00:39:44.601  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 25433 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8334 hours (347 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 68 81 76 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00768168 = 7766376

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 a0 81 76 40 00      00:44:32.236  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 80 76 40 00      00:44:28.544  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 7f 76 40 00      00:44:28.528  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 7e 76 40 00      00:44:28.510  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 7d 76 40 00      00:44:28.493  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 25432 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8333 hours (347 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 68 81 76 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00768168 = 7766376

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 a0 81 76 40 00      01:43:11.164  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 80 76 40 00      01:43:07.468  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 7f 76 40 00      01:43:07.452  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 7e 76 40 00      01:43:07.435  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 7d 76 40 00      01:43:07.419  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 25431 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8333 hours (347 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 18 f5 9e 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x009ef518 = 10417432

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 68 f5 9e 40 00      01:32:05.344  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 68 f4 9e 40 00      01:32:01.582  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 28 00 48 a3 fb 40 00      01:31:59.969  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      01:31:59.757  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  61 08 00 68 54 f9 40 00      01:31:59.757  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 25430 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 8332 hours (347 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 68 81 76 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00768168 = 7766376

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 a0 81 76 40 00      00:05:40.184  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 80 76 40 00      00:05:36.483  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 7f 76 40 00      00:05:36.464  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 7e 76 40 00      00:05:36.443  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 00 a0 7d 76 40 00      00:05:36.427  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

`fdisk -l` output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x755b9e9a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      409599      203776    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          409600   934479871   467035136    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3   *   934479872   976560127    21040128   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       976560128   976771071      105472    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Your `dmesg` output shows lots of errors, check your drive's `S.M.A.R.T.` status and report back

Comment: Updated the `S.M.A.R.T` status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there were no badblocks in sda3 but I found many in sda2. All my stuffs were in sda2. So this read only behaviour was arising only when I was using sda2 like listening to music, working on a project etc. Reading these badblocks in sda2 was causing remounting of sda2 as read only filesystem.

Can I tell fsck not to read these badblocks on sda2(it is NTFS formatted because I'm dual booting )?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have a hardware problem. If this is a sata drive, you could replace the sata cable, or at least check the connectors etc... Otherwise, could you update the question with fdisk -l output.

Comment: Reinserted the hard disk cable. Still getting same behaviour.

Comment: Can you replace the sata cable? The number is I/O error's would suggest hardware not configuration. Can you also show the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Just added the output. See the EDIT. Replacing of cable is not possible any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem on my computer for over 1 year and tried everything to solve the problem. Suddenly Linux goes into read-only mode. If you are editing something you are unable to save and have to execute `fsck` command and reset the computer. The computer is also very slow and freezing all the time. I removed the dual boot and left only Ubuntu, upgraded Ubuntu from version 18.04 LTS to version 20.04 LTS, and it didn't work. What was crucial to solving the problem is the use of the `dmesg` command. The experience didn't work out for me, just this command. The function of this command is to monitor the computer.

In my case, the problem was related to the **SSD incompatibility with Ubuntu**. I used HDD and after I switched to SSD the problem came up. The problem was solved by **updating the SSD firmware**, which was only possible by partitioned Windowns, because Kingston does not have the program to update firmware through Linux. I also installed the dual boot Windowns and Linux, first installing Windows over the entire SSD, then deallocating space through Windowns and installing Ubuntu,  but it is very unlikely that this was the solution to the problem.